# Closure of Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let us consider the usual scalar product on $L_2(a,b)$.
Let $H\subset L_2 $ be a Hilbert space.
Let the closure $\overline{H}$ also be a Hilbert space.

Does it imply $H=\overline{H}$ ?

Comment: A Hilbert space is by definition complete and therefore closed.

Comment: If $L$ is any linear subspace of $L_2$ then $\overline{L}$ must be a Hilbert space.

Comment: Depends whether you assume that the norm of $H$ is compatible with the $L^2$-norm. Otherwise consider $H=W^1(a,b)$.